# Spark SQL: active task is not same for all executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

spark version: 2.4.4
scala: 2.11
deployed on aws emr

cluster conf:
[image]

spark conf:

```
          "--deploy-mode",
          "cluster",
          "--master",
          "yarn",
          "--conf",
          "spark.sql.session.timeZone=Europe/Paris",
          "--conf",
          "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1",
          "--conf",
          "spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g",
          "--executor-cores",
          "5",
          "--conf",
          "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold= 1073741824",
          "--executor-memory",
          "11g",
          "--driver-memory",
          "12g",
```

Q1: I would load a folder with more than 60G, one executer has one more task that others and I don't understand why one more task.

Is it because the result of hash function for one group of value is bigger so this executer needs one more task to finish?
[image]
Q2:  why am I getting only 8 executors?

with my cluster size of 30GB RAM and aws document, more than 22GB is available for application, that is why I configure 11GB each executor and I'm expectin 20 executors since I have 10 machines.
[image]

If I set **--executor-memory 6g**, spark will launch at most 20 executors, and if I set **--executor-memory 8g**, spark will launch at most 14 executors. I doute something is not really clear about AWS EMR and the capacity of each machine.

Comment: It seems like there are 8 worker nodes, therefore you have 8 executors, one per worker node by default. You can change that number by setting `--num-executors` to more than 1.

Comment: @oldwooki If you check the first image, you will see a cluster of 10 machines. since I only set executor ram to have 2 executors per machine, I think spark is smart enough to launch 20 executors, isn't that the behavior of spark? I will try to force num-executors to see.

Comment: you should check the documentation how spark uses the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set `--num-executors` to `2` or more to see what happens?

Follow the rules mentioned in this guide of best practices of tunning Spark Applications: [Distribution of executors cores and memory for Spark Application](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html/).

Comment: --num-executors defines the total number of executors and I tried 20 but I still only have 8 when executor ram is set to 11G.